# Input from KeyListener isn't recognized

Tags: java, input, jframe, jpanel, keylistener

I was in the middle of creating a low-level game which requires key input. So, as usual, I imported the `KeyListener` and `KeyEvent` libraries. I created the three required methods: `keyPressed`, `keyReleased`, `keyTyped`. Then I added a `keyListener` to the class "testJPanel" and, in the `keyPressed` method, I created a `switch` to check whether a certain button has been pressed or not. As for the `keyReleased` and `keyTyped` methods, I chose to leave them empty/blank. To me, everything seems fine and dandy but `Java` doesn't seem to want to register my keyboard inputs: when I press the up arrow key, the program should print "Test", but, sadly, it doesn't. Why's that? Any and all help would be appreciated.

**testJFrame.java**

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class testJFrame extends JFrame {

    public testJFrame() {
        setTitle("A test application");
        setSize(500, 500);
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setFocusable(true);

        add(new testJPanel());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testJFrame testJFrame = new testJFrame();
    }

}
```

**testJPanel.java**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class testJPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

    public testJPanel() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(15, this);
        timer.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void update() {
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        update();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
        switch(k.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            System.out.println("Test");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your panel has to be focusable and it has to have focus in order to recive KeyEvent. add

`setFocusable(true);`

to your panel constructor and change your testFrame constructor like this

```
testPanel = new testJPanel();
add(testPanel);
testPanel.requestFocusInWindow();
```

requestFocusInWindow() must be called after you add the panel.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the JPanel focusable:

```
testPanel.setFocusable(true);
testPanel.requestFocusInWindow();
```

Also if you only want to use the keyPressed method() from the KeyListener. You can use the KeyAdapter class instead:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestJFrame extends JFrame {

    public TestJFrame() {

        setTitle("A test application");
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel testPanel = new JPanel();
        testPanel.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                super.keyPressed(e);
                switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                        System.out.println("Test");
                }
            }
        });
        add(testPanel);
        testPanel.setFocusable(true);
        testPanel.requestFocusInWindow();

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestJFrame();
    }
}
```